# Is Google really trying to find admin.php?

Tags: googlebot

I noticed my error log had this.
The IP, 35.205.21.104, located to Google.

```
[Mon Apr 30 10:07:16.373485 2018] [:error] [pid 15476] [client 35.205.21.104:51858] File does not exist: /home/mysite/public_html/admin.php
```

We never submitted that url to Google.
Could that be someone on Google sites/blog or other app trying to hack my site?

I'd hate to deny them in htaccess if it's Googlebot acting innocent.

Comment: This is more of a site admin question than a programming question.  You might be better off on one of the SE sites where managing a website is more relevant.. Off hand, I'd say probably that site is testing to see if your site is using a CMS or other application that has such a page in order to attempt to hack it.

Comment: By that logic Amazon is responsible for a lot of DDoSes! Don't confuse the host with the actor. Just because Google own 35.205.21.104 doesn't mean Google is the one making the request. Look deeper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a google cloud ip address (which could be anyone) but it is not Googlebot (which has reverse ptr something like crawl-(.*).googlebot.com.)

This ip is:
host 35.205.21.104
104.21.205.35.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 104.21.205.35.bc.googleusercontent.com.

So, No. That is certainly not Googlebot.

Answer (score 1):

Google will crawl your entire site without you submitting any url to them.  If any of the pages on your site link to admin.php, then google will try to access and catalog it.

You can find more information about how to verify that it is a true googlebot here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553

You can find more information on how googlebot works and how to block it here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182072?hl=en